# How to solve an overdetermined system of equations defining the dependent variables?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a simple system of six equations and four variables, namely, $F,G,K$ and $L$. I need to solve the system for $F$ and $L$ in terms of $G$ and $K$,that is

$$
F(G,K) \,\, ,\\
L(G,K) \,\, ,
$$
but I don't have any idea of how can I command the Mathematica do it. Lately I'm using the command `Solve` to do that.

This is the system of equation that I'm treating with:

```
eq1=F + G == H + J

eq2=I F ω - I G ω == I H Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]] - I J Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]]

eq3=E^(I a Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]]) H + E^(-I a Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]]) J ==  E^(I a ω) K + E^(-I a ω) L

eq4=I E^(I a Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]]) H Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]] - I E^(-I a Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]]) J Sqrt[ω^2 - Subscript[V, 0]] == I E^(I a ω) K ω - I E^(-I a ω) L ω

eq5=E^(I b ω) K + E^(-I b ω) L == 0

eq6=I E^(I b ω) K ω - I E^(-I b ω) L ω == 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In fact you want to find the solution of 6 equations with respect to 4 variables: F, L, ,J and H. The fact that you are not interested in the values of J and H plays no role. In this case, however, your system is over-determined. You only need 4 equations to do that. Then `Solve` will do the job. Note that `K` is reserved in Mma, you should not use it.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, Thank you mate, I think that my problem now is with mathematics. Can you draft and solution for this problem?

Comment: No. As I explained above the mathematical statement of the problem is incorrect. I do not know, how to make a correct statement, since it depends on the problem you solve. You know this problem, while I do not.

Comment: I'll edit the question to fix the mathematical statement.

Answer (score 1):

I redefined the equations with lower cases.

```
eq = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6};

Solve[Eliminate[eq, l], f]
```

> {{f -> -g + h + j}}

```
Solve[Eliminate[eq, f], l]
```

> {{l -> -E^(2 I b \ω) k}}

Comment: It didn't work, I need $F(G,K)$ and $L(G,K)$.....